# Javascript object getting undefined in fixed-length for loop

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object that I parse using jQuery's parseJSON function. I assign one of the child objects to a local variable which I then iterate over using a for loop as follows:

```
var posts = feedObj["posts"];
content+= "<h2 title=\"" + feedDescription + "\"><a href=\"" + feedPermalink + "\">" + feedTitle + "</a></h2>";
content+= "<ul class=\"feedList\">";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     console.log(posts[i]["postTitle"]);
     var postTitle = posts[i]["postTitle"];
     if((typeof posts[i] != "undefined") || postTitle != null) {
          content+= "<li>";
          console.log("AJ::PostTitle"+postTitle);
          content+= "<a href=\"" + decodeURIComponent(posts[i]["permaLink"])  + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + unescapeHTML(postTitle) + "</a>";
           content+= "</li>";
     }
}
```

For some reason, the `var postTitle = posts[i]["postTitle"];` always gives the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postTitle' of undefined`

I have no idea why this is happening. The console statement prints out the postTitle correctly but the assignment always fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you add a `console.log(posts[i]);` before your existing log statement? It looks like one of the indexes in your `posts` array is undefined, and you may be getting the error from your log statement instead.

Comment: @Chris that was the issue. Changing it to posts.length in the for loop condition check fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

Add the check condition for the array object

```
for (var i = 0; i < posts.length ; i++) {
```

Maybe the array you are referring to might not have 10 entries in it. The later approach should solve the problem..

Comment: Fantastic. That was it. I added some additional data sources which were causing this failure. Thank You :)

Comment: @AJ. ..Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the first ten posts, replace

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

with

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10 && i < posts.length; i++) {
```

Comment: +1 for this answer as well. Although, I'm going to move the limit to the server side instead of the client side to also limit the data being transferred

Comment: What if the number of posts is greater than 10? This will fail...

Comment: @Ian There is a reason why I said "It should work as I tested it", you are wrong

Comment: Oh, because you tested it, it works perfectly? Doesn't look like it - http://jsfiddle.net/4HGXU/3/ . If the array is bigger than 10 items, or if any of the items are falsey (like `0`), this doesn't work.

Comment: @Robert00001 Ahh yes. I didn't realize you were trying to get only the first 10 items anyways (not sure if the OP wanted that, but...). But now it works as it should

Comment: @Ian: Yes I did want only the first 10 items...

Answer (score -2):

Use `foreach` instead of fixed-length for loop.

Comment: Or just a for loop, the correct way

Comment: @Ian well, yes, that's covered in your answer, but the language added a `foreach` concept so you aren't exposed to errors from using the `for` loop the correct way.  It's harder to use incorrectly so should be preferred.

Comment: What errors are you exposed to in a for loop? Items that aren't defined?

Comment: @Ian - um, yes?  The one that this post is about?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between being `undefined` and "not defined" in an array? They're totally different, especially when it comes to `forEach`. `forEach` skips over not defined elements, not elements that have the value `undefined`. http://jsfiddle.net/mTjac/

Comment: @Ian fixed-length for loops will happily read past the end of the array if the index exceeds the bounds.  foreach will not do this.  This is why you should use foreach.  Anyway feel free to research on your own if you still don't understand this.

Comment: I understand it fully, you don't understand how to use a for loop **correctly** though. Setting a fixed, unrelated bounds is not correct. If you run the for loop like I or Sushanth proposed, there's no reason why it will run outside the bounds. And thanks for the downvote...did you downvote Sushanth too?