# Submit form using jQuery not working from a pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body onload="load()">
       <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>
       <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

       <div id="container">
           <form id="inputFrm" action="/hello" method="post">
               <input name="value" id="myValue" value=1000 size=8 />
               <input name="symbol" id="mySymbol" size=10 />
               <input type="submit">
               <input type="button" id="mySubmitBtn" value="MySubmit">
               </table>
           </form>
       </div>
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#mySubmitBtn").click(function ()
               {
                   var value =document.forms["inputFrm"]["myValue"].value;
                   var symbol =document.forms["inputFrm"]["mySymbol"].value;

                   alert(value)
                   alert(symbol)

                   $("#inputFrm").submit();
               });
           });
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This HTML code stands for a separate window which is opened by another page. For example, imagine that this HTML is returned by a server as a response to a 'new' request:

```
window.open('/new')
```

On this window, the form is not submitted by the jQuery submit function call.

What am I doing wrong here?

I've looked at similar posts and didn't find an answer to this specific code.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Are the alerts coming up at least?

Answer (score 3):

For the id selector you need `#` as a prefix of id. You can read more about selector in *[Category: Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)*.

#### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/VJL8d/)

Change

```
$("inputFrm").submit();
```

to

```
$("#inputFrm").submit();
```

You also need to set the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) of **[form](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)** action tag, supposing you want to post to `hello.php`:

```
<form id="inputFrm" action="hello.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks, in the original code I didn't have this typo, and this still doesn't work when the html code stands for a separate window which is opened by another page.
For example, imagine that this html is returned by a server as a response to a 'new' request:
window.open('/new') 
On this window the form is still not submitted. Any ideas??

Comment: editing the question with the typo fix, and adding that this doesn't work when this code stands for a new window

Comment: you need to provide url in for action, may be hello.php and make sure hello.html exists in the same folder your current page is.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it exists or not. when pressing the button of type submit it presents that the page is not found, and on the mySubmitBtn it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

@Adil's answer solves your form submit problem but you have another problem. You are attaching your Javascript to a button click instead of the form's submit event. The problem with that is if the user presses the enter key to submit your form, your Javascript code will not execute.

Instead you should bind to the form's `.submit()` event:

```
        $('#inputFrm').submit(function(){

            var value =document.forms["inputFrm"]["myValue"].value;      
            var symbol =document.forms["inputFrm"]["mySymbol"].value;              

            alert(value)
            alert(symbol)

            return false;           
        });
```

Also don't forget to `return false` if you want to prevent the form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Just do -

```
$("form#inputFrm").submit();
```

Comment: `#inputFrm` is enough, since the ID is unique there is no need to specify the element type.

Comment: @MrCode Why not `$("body form#inputFrm:first")` ? :)

Comment: @Ian you didn't specify the html tag `$("html body form#inputFrm:first")` :)

Comment: You both right. So as ID is unique i need to specify only $("#inputFrm").submit();

Comment: @MrCode I hate when I forget that. You just have to remember - "Start every jQuery selector with **html**". If we're gonna get serious, it might as well be `$("html body form#inputFrm:first").filter(function () { if ($(this).is("*")) {return true;} });`

Comment: @Ian the only thing I would add to that is a new function: `if(isComputerOn()) // we're good`, just to be on the safe side

Comment: @Ian don't know why you got downvoted, +1 for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728943/javascript-object-getting-undefined-in-fixed-length-for-loop/13728996#13728996

Comment: @MrCode Haha thanks, I don't know why either. I was having an argument with a fellow answerer in their answer so I feel like they might have. Either way, not too worried. It's just funny - I posted the answer like 15 seconds after the accepted and they were like identical. I would understand no upvotes, but downvotes? I'm sure people who read it will see the accepted answer and mine and understand the accepted answer is correct and not worry either.

Answer (score 0):

The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. It can only be attached to  elements.

HTML:

```
<form action="yourfile.html">
    <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    return false;
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Other way is doing Ajax:

#### HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="" name="fname" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="lname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'email.php',
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function (serverResponse) { /*success*/ },
        error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /*handler errors*/ }
    });
});
```